# NSUserNotification() onclick in OS X

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsusernotification

How can I make a notification clickable?

I want that when a user clicks the notification on the Mac, Safari opens with the specified link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To respond to clicks on a `userNotification` object, you need to implement `NSUserNotificationCenterDelegeate`'s `userNotificationCenter:didActivateNotification:` method.